# use js change var str="are you okay" to are| you| okay|

Tags: javascript

```js
var str="are  you okay"
```

I want to change this str like this

`are| you| okay|`

Here is my code

```js
function split() {
  var str = "are   you okay",
      res = ""

  var arr = str.trim().split(/\s+/)
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res += arr[i] + "|"
  }
  
  return res;
}
```

**so I don't know how to return the result like** `are| you| okay|`

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? maybe try `+"| "` (with a space)

Comment: Use this `res=str.replaceAll(' ','|');`

Comment: @SiddhantVarma won't work, as it would return `are|||you|okay`

Comment: NB: your substitution is not consistent - why require `| ` _between_ words but just `|` at the end?

Comment: `res = str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '| ') + '|'`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue that approach all you really need is [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a quick little `join` on the end:

```js
function split(str) {
  return str.trim().split(/\s+/).map(s => `${s}| `).join('').trim();
}

console.log(split("are   you okay"));
```

Note that ES6 makes this pretty easy with [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

You could also do this with a simple regular expression if you're inclined:

```js
function split(str) {
  return str.replace(/\s+/g, '| ');
}

console.log(split("are   you okay"));
```

Where here the `/g` flag means "global" as in "replace all instances". By default it will just do the first.

Comment: `.map` version adds extraneous space to the end of the output.

Comment: @Alnitak Added a `trim()` call.

Comment: @tadman sure, that fixes it, but the call to `.split` followed by `.map` and `.join` is a lot more expensive than a simple `.replace` and then a concat of the file `|`.

Comment: @Alnitak There's obviously more than one way to tackle this problem. I've presented two cases here. The first is a closer adaptation of the original code.

Comment: Just doing a `.join('| ')` of the `split` result would be a closer adaption.

Answer (score 0):

There is a shorter solution. You can first remove double spaces:

```
var str = "are   you okay";
var nospaces = str.replace(/\s+/g,' ').trim();
```

and then replace spaces with `|` :

```
var final_str = nospaces.replace(' ', '| ');
```

Comment: or do the trim first, and then replace any number of spaces directly with `| ` using only one `.replace` call.

Answer (score 0):

You could use combination of [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to separate each space, [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to return words and [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to merge them back into one word:

```js
var str="are  you okay";

const modifiedstr = `${str.split(/\s+/).filter(e=> e != '').join('| ')}|`;
console.log(modifiedstr);
```

Comment: I personally wouldn't use a template string just to add the trailing `|`.

Answer (score 0):

This produces the desired output:

```
const split = (str) => str.trim().replace(/\s+/g, '| ') + '|';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code look good you have to just do this:

```js
function split() {
  var str = "are   you okay",
      res = ""

  var arr = str.trim().split(/\s+/)
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res += arr[i] + "| "; // add space after | sign
  }
  
  return res.trim(); // to remove last space
}

var string = split()
console.log(string)
```

Or you can do this:

```js
function split(str) {

  return str.trim().split(/\s+/).join('| ')+'|';
}

var str = "are  you okay";
var result = split(str);
console.log(result)
```